# Just curious about title in Soundcloud.com

Tags: html, google-chrome

Someone realized the title of `soundcloud.com` is slightly larger than the other tabs on a web browser (specifically `Google Chrome`). Has this been coded within the website? if so how?

The font weight of `Deadmau5` looks slightly larger than the text `html - Just curious...`.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are talking about. Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: Instinct tells me that those are unusual Unicode characters.  Which URL does this happen with?

Comment: It probably has something to do with the "play" icon before the name.

Comment: What SLaks suggests is the only way I can see this happening, too. (no repro in Chrome on OS X by the way - for me, the characters all look the same http://i.stack.imgur.com/vToGE.png)

Comment: I inspect the title tag and no unusual unicode char aparently. In my browser, this happens with any song playing.

Comment: Quick note, probably Soundcloud not Soundclound ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, ▶ char apply bold on words around the char,
try that:

- open console (type F12 on chrome and click "console" tab)
- type: `document.title = "aaa - aaa▶aaa aaa - aaa";`

only 1st and last "aaa" will be in normal font size.

more info about this char here: http://www.charbase.com/25b6-unicode-black-right-pointing-triangle

it seem to be the same with some other char (example: ▧, ◖, ◚, ...)

But it's probably a bug depending on some thinks :

- os
- browser
- font used by os
- truetype activation

Comment: What are you thoughts on why it doesn't work when I add it to this page via web-inspector? see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It can be because of the variation of fonts but easy way of doing it will be using `Ascii` characters. For example:

✁ : `<title>&#9985;</title>`

♛ : `<title>&#9819;</title>`

➨ : `<title>&#10152;</title>`

Try it out with interesting characters from this link: http://nwmtwd.com/misc_character_sets.html

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the character in front of the text, as someone pointed out in the comments. Notice the difference when it is removed

[image]

There must be more to it then this. I added the character from SoundCloud title to this page using web inspector and it didn't seem to have the same effect.

[image]

Comment: is not thats html's font family?

Comment: Yes, I already tried it. And works. @RocketHazmat said the same of you.
I'm waiting him post this comment in an answer. Thank you.

Comment: In my Chrome, works like you did. I copy and past the char. [Click here](http://postimage.org/image/v4q99vi2l/)